# python: Simplest way to sort a list by a calculated value

Tags: python, list, sorting

If I have a master_list (list of lists), I want to know what the simplest way would to sort it by x value (I'll call it score). Score (a float) is derived by calling a function that calculates it based on the items in master_list[i] (a list).

The way I was going about is like this:

```
for i in range(len(master_list):
  # call get_score(master_list[i]) (function that calculates score for master_list[i]) and 
  insert to index 0 in master_list[i]
sorted_list = sorted(master_list)
for i in range(len(master_list):
  master_list[i].pop(0)
```

My function get_score() returns the a single float for one of the lists in master_list

It is important not to modify the original master_list, hence why I am removing score from master_list[i]. What I wish to know is if there is any way to accomplish without adding score to each master_list[i], then removing it.

I also tried something like this but I don't believe it would work:

```
score_sorted = sorted(master_list, key=get_score(iterm for item in master_list))
```

Expected output:
master_list = [['b', 1]['a', 2]['c', 3]]
If the score for master_list[i] are 3, 2, 1 for all items respectively then the ouput would be:
master_list_with_score = [[3,'b', 1][2,'a', 2][1,'c', 3]]
sorted_by_score_master_list = [['c', 3]['a', 2]['b', 1]]

Sorry about the formatting, it's my first time posting. Let me know if there is need for any clarification

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Edit your question to include [mre].

Comment: Can you add what is the current output and what is expected output

Comment: I see you commented on hteza's answer 30 minutes ago already but didn't react to mine. Does it not work for you, either? It should. It's the way to do it.

Comment: @Pychopath I didn't think it would work since get_score () is a function I have to call for for every item in master_list. That's what I thought about doing as well but it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @atv2307 But did it work when you tried it? Your own attempt doesn't work because 1) `get_score` presumably doesn't know what to do with that generator iterator that you give it and 2) `sorted` wants a key *function*, not already computed key values.

Answer (score 1):

You're just supposed to provide the function, `sorted` will call it on the list elements itself.

```
sorted(master_list, key=get_score)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCsIwEETv@Yq9tYF6qPUgQr4khNCmqxY1DZsV2q@PwYjYi3saZt4OE1a@zr47Bkrp0UdGsvcpMijQuhqqBlrTgK76rPZv5bLqjBG4BHQfrnhbrvwaIUY8wwXZRjcT1os8CchHyE/ycIAdLLrNWJyJcbTDWkC7HVPS@sds4Iar@hZLIQJNnuu/PQrKbJnSCw)

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a seperate list of *scores*.

```
master_list = master_list
score = get_score(master_list[i]) # i am assuming it returns a list of scores for the same index in master list
sorted(zip(score, master_list)) # then master list is sorted by the scores
```

If you want a seperated sorted list,

```
sorted_master_list = [i for (score,i) in sorted(zip(score, master_list))]
```

Comment: get_score() returns only a single score (float). So I have to call it for all master_list[i] (all lists inside master_list) individually.